# should I change facebook login code according to February 2013 Breaking Changes?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

In my website I implemented login with facebook.But I got one notification that the Facebook is going to change some functionality permanently.Which describes here [February 2013 Breaking Changes.](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013).

According to this should I change my login code? or It will not effect existing code?

Answer (score 1):

chance is very high, that you should not have to change your implementation.

You only need to adopt something, if you use authenticated referrals. everything else, related to login functionality, keeps unchanged.